# how to force stop android service programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-service

I make tow buttons one to start service and other to stop it 
when I press stop button notify me service is stopped but actually it still working  in the background 
i use timer in my `onStartCommand()` method repeat every second 
is it the reason..? and how to force stop service immediately.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"start..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        private Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+(counter+=1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    },0,1000);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`

and my buttons action :-

```
public void btnStart(View view){

    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));

}
public void btnStop(View view){

   stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
}
```

i found answer ..!
the answer is must cancel timer and timerTask in onDestroy method

Comment: Please put in your Service class and how you call your service so we can troubleshoot :)

Comment: I update the question ..

Comment: I  found my answer in the question itself ..the answer is - must cancel Timer and TimerTask  in onDestroy Method I test it and it works well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simplified description of how to stop services :

`stopSelf()` is used to always stop the current service.

`stopSelf(int startId)` is also used to stop the current service, but only if startId was the ID specified the last time the service was started.

`stopService(Intent service)` is used to stop services, but from outside the service to be stopped.

visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28int%29) for more details

please replace

```
return START_STICKY;
```

by

```
return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

Difference:

**START_STICKY**

the system will try to re-create your service after it is killed

**START_NOT_STICKY**

the system will not try to re-create your service after it is killed

Comment: I use it but not working... problem in  timer and timertask you must cancel them in destroy method

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: thanks for your answer ..I try it but also not working the problem in Timer and TimerTask you should cancel their task first in onDestroy() method and it will stop

Comment: So why don't you just create a function inside you service that stop the timer , and then call it after  you stop the service ?

Comment: i just know that from othe question lik that  and i edit my question .i thought when i stop service it will stop all it task include timer and timerTask

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to stop a service you start you should call stopService(Intent)
ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

Comment: I use this cod  but also  still running

Comment: you should override the onDestory() method and stop your timer on it.